# Solving $y' = -k \sqrt{x}$ without integration constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm an AP Calculus AB student, reviewing for the exam tomorrow, and I came across a question I couldn't solve. It was to find the solution for the differential equation $$\frac{dh}{dt} = -k \sqrt{h}$$ with a solution that describes $h$ in terms of $t$ (time) and $k$ (a constant).

I've experimented, but I don't see any way to express this without using the additive constant C. Can anyone help?

The text also specifies that $k$ is in between $0$ and $1$, but I don't know if that's relevant to this section of the problem though.

Thanks!

EDIT: So it is impossible - I'll count that (knowing its impossible is enough information) and consider my question answered. Thanks all!

Comment: Are you given any initial conditions? If so, the constant $C$ can be evaluated.

Comment: There is no way to give a correct solution without the integration constant. There are an infinite of solutions to most differential equations (I want to say "all", but I'm sure someone can come up with some pathological counterexample), and the $C$ is there to capture them all. The moment you fix a certain value of $y$, say $y(1)=5$, for instance, then the constant may be dealt with, but until then, it _must_ be there.

Comment: Perhaps it could help if you told us exactly in what context this differential equation comes up. Does it just ask you to find the general solution to that differential equation, or does is there a more physical context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dh}{dt}=-k\sqrt{h}$$
$$\int\frac{dh}{\sqrt{h}}=\int-k.dt$$
$$2\sqrt{h}=-kt+C$$

$$h=\big{(}\frac{C-kt}{2}\big{)}^2$$